# Missing repo name in dnf's configuration

Tags: centos, dnf

Whenever I use dnf i get the warning:

```
Repository 'amdgpu-pro-local' is missing name in configuration, using id.
```

Im not quite clear on what name is missing, since there is a name  in the message. Also I assume its the config of dnf ?

I would be very grateful for any answers or pointers. Im quite new to the centos world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you configure a `yum` or `dnf` repository, you create a `.repo` file in the `/etc/yum.repos.d` directory. It should look like this:

```
[epel]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - $basearch
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/$basearch
metalink=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-7&arch=$basearch&infra=$infra&content=$contentdir
failovermethod=priority
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-7
```

Your error means that the **name=** entry is missing. Note that this is just a warning, the behaviour should not change!

Comment: is the name for me, the user, just as an easy way to remember ? Or is it supposed to be meaningful for others?

Comment: It is just used to visualize, for example when running `dnf repolist`, so it should be human-readable and preferably meaningful... but it will work all the same if you name it `abc`...

Answer (score 0):

I don't mean to sound like a smartass, but;

```
Repository 'amdgpu-pro-local' is missing name in configuration, using id.
```

That is technically a warning, not an error - as it states, in the absence of a declared name, it uses somekind of an id number (for some purpose). To "fix" this, you'd just have to declare a **name** variable in the *.repo config file of yours, like this:

```
name=AMD GPU Pro repository
```

Comment: Fixed the question by replacing "error" with "warning".

Comment: I'm still wondering though what `amdgpu-pro-local` is, if not the name. How do you know the id is a number?

Comment: you can check your /etc/yum.repos.d/ directory - i'd bet there's a file named "amdgpu-pro-local.repo" where dnf generates that message from.

Comment: Yeah the file exists, and the problem was that there was `Name` instead of `name`. But there is no `id=...` .

Answer (score 0):

file location: `/etc/yum.repos.d/amdgpu-pro-local.repo`

content:

```
[amdgpu-pro-local]
name=AMD GPU
baseurl=file:///var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
```

This should fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the problem today, problem is AMD does provide a bad .repo file. Although there is a "Name=" Variable set it seems dnf is case-sensitive on this so solution is to simply change it into "name=". Worked for me.